# How to display different image background in report?

Tags: jasper-reports

**Here is a set of specifications:**

1. Total Report's Page: 10 pages for example.
2. There are two image background: background-1.png and background-2.png.
3. "background-1.png" should display on page 1,3,5,7,...of report
4. "background-2.png" should display on page 2,4,6,8,...of report

Is it possible to do this in *iReport/Jaspersoft Studio*? And how?

Answer (score 2):

In the image expression, you might try adding a check of whether the page number is odd or even. For example: `$P{REPORT_PAGE}%2 == 1 ? *path_to_image*/background-1.png : *path_to_image*/background-2.png`